# density plot with bubbles

Tags: plotting, graphics

How can I plot 3d list data by list density plot with bubbles I want to show some localization states (max , min) by bubbles with different colors
thanks

Comment: bubbles? What does that mean?

Comment: bubbles like colorful circles that third component of data make colors of this circles

Comment: Maybe [`BubbleChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BubbleChart.html) or [`BubbleChart3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BubbleChart3D.html) is what you are looking for?

Comment: I saw that but I couldn't understand how can I use it?

Comment: You can use `Show` to join arbitrary graphics objects. e.g. a `BubbleChart` and a densityplot. However, without any data provided from your side, it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 2):

```
data = RandomReal[10, {1000, 3}];

{min, max} = MinMax[data[[All, 3]]];

minPts = Select[data, #[[3]] == min &];

maxPts = Select[data, #[[3]] == max &];

ListDensityPlot[data,
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[10], Green, Point[Most /@ minPts], Red, 
   Point[Most /@ maxPts]}]
```

[image]